# How to make inner scroll bar scrollable easily within another scrollbar?

Tags: android, listview

I have a problem that have a ListView which can be scrolled inside the ScrollView. If I want to scroll the ListView, it tends to scroll the scrollbar of the scrollView instead of the listView.

Is there a way to prevent from scrollview scroll when scrolling the ListView?

```
scrollview.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {  
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        descriptionTextView.getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);
        return false;
    }
});
```

Comment: You should never put a ListView inside a ScrollView.

Comment: You should never use a HorizontalScrollView with a ListView, since ListView takes care of its own scrolling. Most importantly, doing this defeats all of the important optimizations in ListView for dealing with large lists, since it effectively forces the ListView to display its entire list of items to fill up the infinite container supplied by HorizontalScrollView.